# How to make a scatter plot that separated by color in matplotlib.pyplot

Tags: python, if-statement, matplotlib, plot

[image]

I want to make plot like that...

There are 3 condistions..

1. if x > 700 -> col='blue'
2. if x <= 700 and y > -2    -> col='black'
3. if x <= 700 and y <= -2   -> col='red' and marker='*'

How can I make a plot like that??

[image]

Comment: Try writing some code and share it if it doesn't work...

Comment: plot(x, y,


     col=ifelse(y < Coff & x > Nor,'green', ifelse( y < Coff,'red', ifelse( x > Nor, 'blue', "black"))),


     pch = ifelse( y < Coff, '*','.'),


     cex = ifelse( y < Coff, 1.5, 3),


     ylim = c(-20.0,20.0),


     ylab = 'Z-score', xlab = 'smaple'


)


grid()

Comment: above code is R code.. I can maek scatter plot using R..

but I want to use python!!

Comment: then write some python code, there is no lack of tutorial out there.

Comment: I tried above python code and plot..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have your exact data, so I am just going to create my own dataset. The simplest way to do this is to store the three separate color types you wish to generate in three separate set of arrays. Check the below code.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random

x_val = [random.randint(600, 800) for i in range(500)]
y_val = [random.randint(-4, 0) for i in range(500)]
blue_plot = [(x, y) for (x, y) in zip(x_val, y_val) if x > 700]
black_plot = [(x, y) for (x, y) in zip(x_val, y_val) if x <= 700 and y >= -2]
red_plot = [(x, y) for (x, y) in zip(x_val, y_val) if x <= 700 and y <= -2]

def separate_x_y(val):
    x = [x for (x, _) in val]
    y = [y for (_, y) in val]
    return x, y

blue_x, blue_y = separate_x_y(blue_plot)
black_x, black_y = separate_x_y(black_plot)
red_x, red_y = separate_x_y(red_plot)

# Main part of code
plt.scatter(blue_x, blue_y, color = 'blue')
plt.scatter(black_x, black_y, color = 'black')
plt.scatter(red_x, red_y, color = 'red', marker = '*')
plt.xlim(550, 850)
plt.ylim(-6, 2)
plt.show()
```

You will get plot like this.

[image: Plot]